# Supporting Angular 8 components in legacy applications in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

I am currently evaluating the possibility to include Angular 8 elements in legacy applications.

I have a little component and we include it by building the angular application, bundling the resulting js files *(runtime.js, polyfills.js, polyfills-es5.js, scripts.js and main.js)* and including them to our legacy application *(A jsp application with lots of javascript and Spring controller backend)*.

The component itself loads a list of entities from a Spring Controller and renders the content of those entities (by calling Spring Controllers again).
By itself, the Angular application works in Chrome AND in IE (we use IE 11).

But within the legacy application, it only works in Chrome, but not in IE. The reason is that it is a single page application where a lot happens after page load by javascript calls. The problem seems to be that the angular scripts are included on page load and after navigating through the application and the angular component is inserted (by javascript) into the DOM the scripts are not called properly. There are no error messages whatsoever. The tags get included, and even a part of the HTML template of the angular component. Even the request to the Spring controller happens and we get a valid response. The response is just not processed and rendered.

Two things we found out so far:

When we triggered the Angular changeDetection manually, the component was rendered properly.

When we include the angular tags (by writing it directly into the HTML or appending it with javascript, both works) **before** we include the Angular scripts, everything works fine.

So, there must be a problem with the order of things happening in the application. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Like I've said, in Chrome, everything works fine (also in our legacy application) only in IE it doesn't work.

Please note that I am an Angular Newbie, so please use simple words =)

**EDIT**

An easier example is this:

When I just insert my component into the template of our application (without any further content or javascript libraries...

...this works:

```
<script>
   $("body").append($(document.createElement("ce-favorite-gridlist")));
</script>

<script src="js/angular/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/polyfills-es5.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/main.js"></script>
```

... and this doesn't work:

```
<script src="js/angular/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/polyfills-es5.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/main.js"></script>

<script>
   $("body").append($(document.createElement("ce-favorite-gridlist")));
</script>
```

I think this is the main problem, because the template is rendered and after that we include the component into our application later.

Is there anything I could do to get the second example to work?

P.S. I know that I can bundle the scripts, we just wanted to make sure nothing goes wrong when bundling the scripts...

Comment: Can you combine all the code in one script tag and call it before referencing other scripts?

Comment: Yes, like I've said in the P.S.: We did that before, same behavior. We just wanted to make sure nothing goes wrong with the bundling, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: I try to find but did not get any other way to fix this issue for IE. I suggest you to make a test with bundling the scripts and check that everything works fine with IE.